# Has Gambit ever charged / blown up a living creature?

Tags: marvel, x-men, gambit

I know [Gambit](http://www.uncannyxmen.net/sites/default/files/images/spotlight/gambit00.jpg)'s usually a good guy, but has he ever charged / blown up a living creature?

Possibly an arch-nemesis that pushed him too far or some mindless beast?

Comment: He can only charge innate objects isn't it? There is an elsewhere story where he charges and explode the earth.

Comment: The MCU tag is strange, Gambit doesn't exist there since he's a mutant, and that term is verboten in the MCU!

Comment: @TheHonorableNedStark he's in that terrible [Wolverine:Origins](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0458525/) movie isn't he?

Comment: I think so, but I couldn't go with all that horrible Wolverine movies saga. They botched one of my favorite stories, where Logan gets his adamantium overcoating (and we learn that his wild hair is growing back to its familiar shape as part of the healing factor!) and whatnot.

Comment: @Daft: he is indeed, but that’s not part of [the Marvel Cinematic Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe).

Comment: Except [it is now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe#Integration_of_assets_from_21st_Century_Fox), [probably](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool_%26_Wolverine).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Gambit battles Daken in *[DAKEN: DARK WOLVERINE (2010) #8](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/30064/daken_dark_wolverine_2010_8)*, and although he doesn't fully blow him up, he blows the flesh off his arm...

From [Comic Vine](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/gambit/4005-1499/):

> Daken approaches them after they leave and gets into a bloody fight with X-23 in the streets before convincing her that they should work together to get Malcolm Colcord. As Daken meets with Colcord later in the night, Gambit and Laura attack them. While Laura is torturing Colcord, Daken approaches Gambit and offers him a partnership. Gambit turns him down as they have a vicious fight. **Gambit winds up blowing the flesh off of Daken's arm before realizing the fight was a distraction as Colcord has knocked out X-23**. Daken knocks Gambit out from behind.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

[This source](http://www.comicvine.com/profile/god_spawn/blog/avx-misconception-can-gambit-charge-organic-matter/80752/) found a lot of examples of Gambit charging organic material:

- X-Men Legacy 214: Gambit charges Shaw
- X-23's series issue 5 or 6: Gambit charges himself
- Daken: Dark Wolverine #8: Gambit charges Daken's fist
- X-Men Vol 3 #10: Gambit charges a lizard

Comment: I own the comic of the Cap/Gambit fight in that link so I was always under the impression he couldn't charge organic material.  +1 for the link so that I don't make a fool of myself in the future ;)

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**, Gambit can charge living creatures. He has charged and detonated both Wolverine and Hammerhead. Another version of him, the "New Sun", blew up ("atomized") everything and everyone in his world.

#### Wolverine

[image: Gambit charges Wolverine's claws in "X-Men '97".]

In the premiere episode of the animated series *X-Men '97* (2024), Gambit pulls off a slick teamwork move with Wolverine. He charges Wolverine's adamantium claws. Wolverine then gets launched towards Master Mold's neck and stabs it, resulting in the villain’s head getting caught in the explosion.

We don't see exactly how this affected Wolverine, who seems to be unharmed (or maybe his healing factor shrugged it off). Still, a pretty cool mutant combo attack!

[image: Wolverine gets launched towards Master Mold's neck and stabs it.]

---

#### Hammerhead

In [*Ultimate X-Men* #14](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Ultimate_X-Men_Vol_1_14) (2002), Gambit fights Hammerhead. In a brutal move, Gambit detonates Hammerhead's head from the inside.

[image: *Ultimate X-Men #14 panels depicting the above]

---

#### Everything and everyone on Earth

A version of Gambit / Remy LeBeau who calls himself the "New Sun", had the full potential of his powers unleashed. He blew up everything and everyone in his world, "atomizing animal, vegetable, and mineral alike". He discovers that multiple versions of Gambit / Remy LeBeau across different universes have similarly destroyed their worlds using their powers.

[image: Gambit Vol. 3 #24 page where the New Sun explains the above]

- *Gambit* Vol. 3 #24 (2000)

Comment: Since we only see Gambit charging Wolverine's adamantium claws here, this doesn't clearly demonstrate that he can charge organic material.

Comment: @LogicDictates That may be true, but the question says "living creature," not "organic material." ☺️ And who knows, maybe the bone part got charged too.

Comment: I think the answer was worth posting, but it's debatable whether charging Wolverine's non-living adamantium implants counts as charging a living creature. I guess it depends on whether one views those implants as a part of Wolverine's body, or as foreign objects attached to his body. Either way, just in terms of how Gambit's powers work, I think it's important to note that he may not have charged any living matter here, and that he may not have been capable of doing so.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the claws of this cartoon version of Wolverine may have been composed of pure adamantium. In the comics, the claws were originally supposed to be pure adamantium and Wolverine was retconned to have bone claws in _Wolverine Vol. 2 #75_ (November, 1993), after the start of _X-Men: The Animated Series_. As far as I know, the retcon was never established in the cartoon.

Comment: @LogicDictates I asked about it here: [How was adamantium bonded with Wolverine’s skeleton? Surface coating, or was the metal infused into the bone?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/286415/7957)

Comment: To me, the adamantium in Wolverine's body is foreign matter, regardless of whether his bones are merely coated with it or infused with it. Also, the answer to your question likely depends on the version of the character and the writer. In the case of _X-Men: The Animated Series_, Wolverine's claws were likely intended to be pure adamantium when the series first began airing in 1992, but Marvel now has the opportunity to establish that he has bone claws in the new series, if they want to.

Answer (score 2):

There is two answers. One, during the Gambit solo series, an alternative Universe Gambit called New Son, an energy God version with his powers maxed out, has killed everybody on his Earth, because the powers flared out. The plot states this has happened in multiple universes.

The second answer is yes, some versions of Gambit have or atleast threatened to blow someone up. One Gambit killed Hammerhead by charging his metal skull. Another threatened to do this to Wolverine adamantium skeleton in a fight.